# Linearization of $f(x) = \alpha_1\ast e^{-\alpha_2x} + \alpha_3\ast ln(\alpha_4\ast x)$

Tags: numerical-methods, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra, linearization

I have data points that I need to fit a line of best fit to it. I found that they follow a pattern described by the function:
$$f(x) = \alpha_1\ast e^{-\alpha_2x} + \alpha_3\ast ln(\alpha_4\ast x)$$
Now I need to find the values for $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_4$ that best fit my data.

For that, I was going to use least square fitting but no matter how I try I can't seem to transform $f(x)$ into a linear equation no matter what operation I apply to it, can somebody give me some light on how I can linearize $f(x)$ or if that is even possible.